# Can Django be used to combine both webapp and moblie api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use django framework to write a web site with static/dynamic pages (I will not be using angular/react - i.e. SPA technology) but I also want the web app to serve as the backend for a mobile app.

What's the best practice here? Can Django alone be used for it? 
Will I need to use Django REST framework?

If you could recommend some specific modules to keep the app as simple as possible and avoid DRY code. That'd be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right pointers in your question already.
Use django-rest-framework to create a rest service, create your web app in django to consume that service, create a mobile app to consume the same rest service.

In general, once you have a rest service, you can build anything on top of it. Just consume the service from whichever platform you want to build for.

I hope that helps.

Comment: How do you output the static views though using django REST framework?  E.g when you go to   site/items/   I want a html page be rendered with a template rather than json.

Comment: Rest would give you standard formats that different platforms can use to communicate. If u want an html page, you'd write the rest-fraemwork url that output json and then create an html page than consume that api to display the html. You may want to read what rest framework really means, how it works and how to consume it to really understand what you are getting into. It's very easy and fun to work with anyway.

Comment: As per my question - I won't go with SPA technology (angular etc.) so I don't want to create a html page that consumes the api. I want to combine traditional template/html views  AND api (which will be used by _separate_ mobile and CLI tools).   How can I achieve this? I.e. when user visits  site/books/     I want a complete stand-alone page/html template to be sent back to user browser with a list of books when visited from browser, and I want JSON response in other cases (CLI , mobile etc). Does REST framework does not allow to share the code (DRY) for both cases ?

Comment: api are not used for SPAs alone. You can consume an api anyhow, the page can be whatever.